# which tense is better in this example?

Tags: past-perfect, past-perfect-continuous

> That day, I had been working in London and I was on my way home when....

or

> That day, I had worked in London and I was on my way home when...

(I am on my way home after the working day)

Answer (score 1):

Depends what you want to say

> *(On)* that day, I **had been** working in London and I was on my way home when....

Has a feeling that you normally ***don't go*** to London, but happened to be in London working.

> *(On)* that day, I **had worked** in London and I was on my way home when...

Has a feeling that you work in London from ***time to time***, and worked in London that day.

> *(On)* that day, I **worked** in London and I was on my way home when...

Has a feeling that you ***habitually*** work in London.